# Got stuck with the leibniz criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \Big(\frac{1}{n^2}+ \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \Big)$

Does the progression converge, absolutely converge or diverge.

I tried it with the Leibniz-criterion, but I dont know how to proof monotony after proofing that it is a zero sequence, because the $(-1)^n$ is not disappearing. I would appreciate it if  u could tell me what criterion i have to use or how I could solve my problem with the monotony. We are allowed to use the root-test, ratio-test, comparisation tests and the leibniz test.

Answer (score 1):

Split the sum into two parts. The sum over $\frac{1}{n^2}$ clearly converges, and the
sum over $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges due to the Leibniz rule.

Comment: thanks I thought about it but wasnt sure if is allowed.